# Geometry - Determine all points along a ray from starting coordinates and direction

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am working on a video game. I need to determine each point along a ray with every x interval with the following information:

- X, Y, Z coordinates of the starting point of the ray, and,
- X, Y, Z coordinates representing the angle of the ray (the game is 3D, from what I can tell the game engine uses Euclidian vectors)

Of course rays are infinite in number, so I need something like "get next point." My idea is to have the computer get the first point, check it, and if that is not successful, get the next point and check it and so on until a specific point fits what I need. Of course, there some be some arbitrary upper limit to prevent the program crashing due to continually checking many rays.

In my game (it's a Minecraft clone for learning purpuses for anyone who knows about that) there is a 3d grid, each cell in the game is filled completly with some material, ie grass or air. I need to determine the first non-air block in the direction the player is looking. The player can be looking in any direction and is not bound to the grid in any way other than their location being represented by a floating point x, y, and z coordinate on the grid.

NOTE: My game engine does not have a built-in feature to do this.

Comment: Do you want to find all points with integer coordinates, or every point? If you want every point you certainly cannot get a next point, since there would be another point between those two. Or could it be you wanted every point with a distance of $1$ between them (or some other number)

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more what this condition is that you want to check? There are many way more efficient algorithms/formulas for stuff like this than just 'try and error', and I think many of those are available in the most common game engines.

Comment: Every point at x intervals would do, as long as the value of x can be as large or as small as I want. Also, I should note that I know very little about math, so please use small words :P. As for what kind of X, Y, and Z values are used, with my limited knowledge of math and after some research, from what I can tell the game engine use Euclidian vectors.

Comment: Kristoffer, I'm not sure if that is an automated message or not, but I know how StackExchange works and I was simply waiting for an answer to become acceptable. I have now accepted my chosen answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, you want to find every cube that a ray passes through, and enumerate them.

The direction he's looking in will be signified by $(d_x,d_y,d_z)\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}$, note that I assume that the direction is a vector starting at the center of the coordinate system, and not from the player.

We can simply enumerate coordinates on the ray with some interval, and discard duplicates, we just have to make sure that the interval is small enough such that we miss no blocks.

If we want this interval to be small enough such that it always ends up in the current or an adjacent block, we want $e$ to be the minumum distance to one of the lines in the grid between the boxes. (If the point is on a line, we discard that one) So let $e$ be that distance then we simply need to normalize the vector to have that size.

---

Finding $e$ is tricky, we need to find the distance from the point to many lines in a grid. For the following I assume that $q$ is the side length between the boxes, and that $x,y,z$ is the coordinate of the point.

We will perform an algorithm 3 times, one for each dimension. Each time we perform it, we are given a number, totaling at $3$ numbers. $e$ is the smallest of those $3$ numbers. The first time we will have $h=x,p=y$, the second time $h=x,p=z$ and the third time will have $h=y,p=z$.

The algorithm is as follows:

> Let $\lfloor x\rfloor_q$ be $x$ rounded down with resolution $q$, and let $[x]_q$ be defined as the smallest of the following two numbers: $(x-\lfloor x\rfloor_q)^2$ and $(q-x+\lfloor x\rfloor_q)^2$
>
> If $[h]_q=[p]_q=0$ then the number returned by the algorithm is $q$.
>
> Otherwise the number returned by the algorithm is $\sqrt{[h]_q+[p]_q}$

---

Let $s=\dfrac1e\sqrt{(d_x)^2+(d_y)^2+(d_z)^2}$, and define:

$$
\begin{align}
\delta_x&=\frac{d_x}s\\
\delta_y&=\frac{d_y}s\\
\delta_z&=\frac{d_z}s
\end{align}
$$

Now simply given a point, calculate the next point with the given formula:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{next $x$}&=x+\delta_x\\
\text{next $y$}&=y+\delta_y\\
\text{next $z$}&=z+\delta_z
\end{align}
$$
Where $x,y,z$ are the coordinates of the previous point. Each of these points will be inside a box on the ray, and you wont miss any because we normalized the direction. Note that we might get the same box several times in a row, so if that's a problem you have to check for duplicates. The starting point is of course the players position.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is very simple and easy to understand, but I am still slightly confused. You seem to be assigning a value to s twice, once with the square root equasion and another time with the Sx, Sy, and Sz. Are these seperate variables (ie. S is just like Sa would be?). Also, How would I determine the value of e? Each box is exactly 2x2 in world units?

Comment: $s,\delta_x,\delta_y,\delta_z$ are all seperate values, and $\delta$ is the greek letter delta commonly used for differences.

Comment: Ok, so I assume that I treat the location of the player as the first X, Y and Z coordinates? Also, what about calculating e? I'm sorry if I'm asking to be spoon feed, but I really know almost nothing about math so I'm not even sure where to begin with calculating e.

Comment: Yes the player is the first location, I'll update the answer about $e$ in a moment. Also, don't worry about being spoonfed, I'm not experiencing any problems with that right now as the question is fine formulated and I understood what you wanted.

Comment: @john01dav Okay, I've updated the answer with $e$

Comment: I just noticed that the $e$ mentioned in this answer might actually be too large in some cases. I'll be updating the answer in a moment with the $e$ we are looking for.

Comment: This answer is now fixed and should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well if $A = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is the start point, and $d =(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ is the direction of the reay, you can parametrize the ray by

$$ p  = a + td = \begin{pmatrix} a_1+td_1 \\ a_2 + td_2 \\ a_3+td_3\end{pmatrix}$$ for $t \in \mathbb R$, or for $t \in [0,1]$ if you want to get a point $p$ that is in between $a$ and $b$.

If your 'minecraft' blocks have a edge length of $e$, you can check whether the point

$$ p = a+t\frac{e}{|d|} d = \begin{pmatrix} a_1+t\frac{e}{|d|}d_1 \\ a_2 + t\frac{e}{|d|}d_2 \\ a_3+t\frac{e}{|d|}d_3\end{pmatrix}$$
 within a block for $t = 0,1,2,3,...$ (until you are within a block)

where $|d| = \sqrt{d_1^2+d_2^2+d_3^2}$ is the length of the vector $d$.

Here I used the idea that if you are outside of block, you can make a step of at least the size $e$ in order not to overshoot the possible first block.

Comment: It isn't an endpoint, it is an Euclidian vector and the starting point that I have. Also, see my edit to the original question.

Comment: I canged my answer accordingly, I hope everything is clear!

Comment: You use a lot of symbols that I've never seen before. Is there any chance you could simplify it a bit? As I said, I know very little about math. Specifically, I don't understand that capital R, the wierd looking E, the large perenthesisie, and the word paramatize.

Comment: @john01dav $\mathbb R$ means all the real numbers, and $\in$ means "in", so $t\in\mathbb R$ means that $t$ is in the set of all real numbers, or equivalently that $t$ is a real number.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl explained it perfectly. $t$ is just an arbitrary real number, and if you increase or decrease $t$ the values you get for $p$ are just the coordinates of points 'sliding' along the given line. For $t=0$ you get $a$ and if you increase $t>0$ you will get further away from you in the given direction.

Comment: @flawr You can actually overshoot a block with the distance you mentioned, for example if $e=1$, and the player is at $(0.7,0.9,0.9)$ and is looking in the direction $(1,1,1)$ you will end up at in a block that only touches by the corner, while we really would like to end up in a box adjacent to our box.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl You are right, I assumed the player is in the same 'integer grid' as the cubes, then it should work the way I suggested.

Comment: @flawr Yeah, if the player is in the integer grid, this works however quote: "The player can be looking in any direction and is not bound to the grid in any way other than their location being represented by a floating point x, y, and z coordinate on the grid."

Comment: @flawr If you use the $e$ mentioned in my answer, this answer should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize a ray using $P_0+tD$ where $P_0=(p_x,p_y,p_z)$ is the starting point of the ray, $D=(d_x,d_y,d_z)$ points in the direction of the ray, and $t$ is any non-negative real number.